# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject in my java restful webservice

Tags: java, json, eclipse

I have write java restful webservice to retrieve the data to JSON Object, but it has the error in below

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2571)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1429)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getMethods(MethodList.java:77)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:116)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:739)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1533)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1297)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:760)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    ... 36 more

1? 03, 2018 2:55:37 ?? org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet HelloWorld Service
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONObject
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2571)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1429)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.getMethods(MethodList.java:77)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:64)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.MethodList.<init>(MethodList.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.modelapi.annotation.IntrospectionModeller.createResource(IntrospectionModeller.java:116)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getAbstractResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:739)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.createAbstractResourceModelStructures(WebApplicationImpl.java:1533)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1297)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:163)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:760)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And Here is my code, But I have write the dependence and set the jar in eclipse

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{status}/status")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public JSONObject checkRefno(@PathParam("status") String status) {
        String ref_no = null;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
         JSONArray array=new JSONArray();
        try {
            String conUrl = "the url cannot show to others"
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl);
            String sql = "SELECT orderid FROM dbo.abc WHERE status = ?";
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, status);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                ref_no = rs.getString("ref_no");
            }
             array.put(ref_no);
             json.put("orderid", array);
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return json;
    }
```

How should I do? And I find some answer that should go to the Deployment Assembly to set jar but my eclipse cannot find this setting,Anyone can help me, Thanks!

Comment: Yet another classpath problem...

Comment: you mean another jar build path is not correct?

Comment: Yes, of course. This means the JSON library is not in the classpath when you deploy it to Tomcat or whatever container you're using

Comment: If you are using maven then just add  [Maven org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20171018) dependency in the POM

Answer (score 0):

While deploying a java dynamic web project, jars files should be set for build path and also same jar files should be added to `lib` folder of `WEB-INF` directory.

class path is set using buildpath option:

[image]

add the copy of jar files into lib folder:

[image]

Comment: But it doesn't work, it still have the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONObject

Comment: it has one error like this
1? 04, 2018 10:55:03 ?? com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse logException
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class org.json.JSONObject, and Java type class org.json.JSONObject, and MIME media type application/octet-stream was not found

Comment: R u using maven ??

Comment: Try adding Genson library to your classpath http://owlike.github.io/genson/. It is a json<>java streaming and databinding api. It integrates well with jersey, to get you running you need 0 configuration. Jersey detects that the library is in your classpath and enables json mapping by delegating to Genson.